# Why Laravel `bcrypt` or Hashing a random string password is mismatched when checking?

Tags: laravel, authentication, hash, bcrypt

I am generating a random string which I want to save or update as new password to an existing user on a `Laravel` app.

This is how I do it in my controller:

```
public function changePassword(){

        // Generate new Password
        $newPassword = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16/2, $crypto));

        $user = Auth::user();

        $user->password = bcrypt($newPassword);

        $user->save();

        if(Hash::check($newPassword, $user->password)){

            return response($user);

        }

        return response('Password Mismatched', 401);
    }
```

The response is giving me the `"Password Mismatched" 401 error`. Why
is it that it gives me a mismatched password?

Comment: what's your driver in `config/hashing.php`?

Comment: @Paras `'driver' => 'bcrypt',`

Comment: hmm does it work with `$newPassword = 'password';`? Also do you have a mutator or accessor in your user model?

Comment: If your `User` model (or whatever is returned by `Auth::user();`) is set to Hash a `password` attribute by default, you might be running into an issue of "hashing a hash". If you can view the DB directly, try saving with `bcrypt()` and without; if both are non-plain-text values, then you know this to be the case.

Comment: @TimLewis excellent! Your theory is true. It's hashing the hash. Therefore I have changed my code from `$user->password = bcrypt($newPassword);` to `$user->password = $newPassword;` instead. Thanks for the idea. If you could create this as an answer I will mark it checked/correct.

Comment: Sure thing. Let me just get that written up. Glad you got it solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how your `User` model is set up, it may be calling `bcrypt()` or `Hash::make()` on the `password` attribute automatically, which, when combined with manually calling the function results in a "hash of a hash" situation. To avoid thing, simply remove the manual call to the function and allow the `User` model to handle it automatically:

```
$user = Auth::user();
$user->password = $newPassword;
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

use `Hash::make()` while saving password to db like this,

```
public function changePassword(){

    // Generate new Password
    $newPassword = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16/2, $crypto));

    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->password = Hash::make($newPassword);

    $user->save();

    if(Hash::check($newPassword, $user->password)){

        return response($user);

    }

    return response('Password Mismatched', 401);
}
```

This might work.

Comment: `Hash::make()` and `bcrypt()` are equivalent functions: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/helpers#method-bcrypt

Comment: @TimLewis Oh, I don't know that till now and i've always used `hash::make()`.